# Weird behavior with indexof method in c#

Tags: c#, substring, indexof

I have this code, where `entities` is a `List <String>` received by parameter. I tried to cast `entities[x]` to string in any way possible, even it already being a string. I also checked `entities[x] is String` always returning `true`.

```
for(int x = 0; x < entities.Count; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entities[x] + " " +  "a pencil g smartboard tabletc pencil ".IndexOf(entities[x]));
}
```

The result is:

```
pencil 30
smartboard 11
tabletc -1
```

Why indexof returns -1 for "tabletc"?

Comment: Please show a complete example, including where you populate `entities`.

Comment: Probably because in entities you have `tabletpc`

Comment: @SwDevMan81 shouldn't it show its position in the string instead of -1 if it is in the string?

Comment: Yeah well I wonder if the result was copy/pasted from the real output or just typed in...

Comment: @KirkWoll `entities` is populated with the content of a file. With it being a string list shouldn't be enough?

Comment: @FredericoSchardong - I'm just guessing that the value in the entities list is spelled differently.

Comment: @MatthewWatson obviously I copied and pasted the output

Comment: @SwDevMan81 entites' values are being outputted, they are what I pasted in the result section.

Comment: @FredericoSchardong In that case, it can't have been spelled differently.

Comment: @MatthewWatson so you agree with me that IndexOf should have returned something different from -1

Comment: There is simply no way you're showing us the actual code: if you were, it would print out `pencil 2` for the first line, since that's the first position of "pencil" in the string. As others have said, double-check that the strings in `entities` are the ones you expect. `IndexOf()` works just fine.

Comment: What is `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`? You copy-paste the characters from the "terminal window" (`cmd` window), but some characters cannot be written to that window, so maybe some strange characters are present that do not show. What does `string.Join(",", entities[2])` return? Or even `string.Join(",", entities[2].Select(ch => ((int)ch).ToString("X4")))`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen `tabletc` and `0008,0074,0061,0062,006C,0065,0074,0063`

Comment: @FredericoSchardong Yeah, that `0008` shouldn't be there.

Comment: @dlev, I see. Any ideas on how I can solve that?

Comment: Here is a new pastebin with the ASCII of all the strings. http://pastebin.com/QtViVurh All make sense now

Comment: Well, one option might be to call `char.IsLetterOrDigit()` before appending the character to the entity.

Comment: @dlev it works just fine: http://pastebin.com/TypgggTe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string from your input begins with a backspace character, ASCII 8.

Try something like

```
"... \btabletc ...".IndexOf(entities[2])
```

where `\b` means the backspace character.

Comment: I solved using @dlev's suggestion: `char.IsLetterOrDigit()`. However, you found the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following program outputs

```
pencil 2
smartboard 11
tabletc 22
```

This program is compilable. What is the output if you try it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        void test()
        {
            var entities = new List<string> { "pencil", "smartboard", "tabletc" };

            for (int x = 0; x < entities.Count; x++)
                Console.WriteLine(entities[x] + " " +  "a pencil g smartboard tabletc pencil ".IndexOf(entities[x]));
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().test();
        }
    }
}
```

If it works as expected, your next step is to see where your input differs.

---

[EDIT]

I looked at your pastebin code, and I tried it with a test file that I created and it worked ok. However when I copy and pasted (from pastebin) the comments that said what the method outputs, I discovered that there was a BEL character and a BS character embedded in it:

```
    //this method outputs:
    //3
   //pencil
    //smartboard
   //tabletc
```

You can't see those characters there, but if you copy/paste the text into Notepad++ they show up. It looks suspiciously like they may have been read from the file and are part of the strings, but they don't show up visibily. But they would affect the string matching.

Those characters have been stripped when I pasted them here on SO, but they are there on pastebin, lines 31 - 35. Try copy/paste them into Notepad++.

Comment: It works as expected, here is my code populating entities http://pastebin.com/mfnEcGBX

Comment: @FredericoSchardong See my latest edit; maybe it's a clue.